# When i call function it's given me error. why?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, validation

**The Error is Appearing**

username function is not calling while i am giving value in it

```
Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'
```

My javascript is:

```
email : { required : true, email : true, remote : { url : baseURL + "checkEmailExists", type :"post"} },
        username :{ required : true, remote : { url : baseURL + "checkUsernameExists", type :"post"} },
        password : { required : true },
```

My controller is:

```
function checkEmailExists()
{
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $email = $this->input->post("email");

    if(empty($id)){
        $result1 = $this->user_model->checkEmailExists($email);
    } else {
        $result1 = $this->user_model->checkEmailExists($email, $id);
    }

    if(empty($result1)){ echo("true"); }
    else { echo("false"); }
}

function checkUsernameExists()
{
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $username = $this->input->post("username");

    if(empty($id)){
        $result = $this->user_model->checkUsernameExists($username);
    } else {
        $result = $this->user_model->checkUsernameExists($username, $id);
    }

    if(empty($result)){ echo("true"); }
    else { echo("false"); }
}
```

and my model is:

```
function checkEmailExists($email, $id = 0)
{
    $this->db->select("email");
    $this->db->from("admins");
    $this->db->where("email", $email);   
    if($id != 0){
        $this->db->where("id !=", $id);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}

function checkUsernameExists($username, $id = '')
{
    $this->db->select("username");
    $this->db->from("admins");
    $this->db->where("username", $username);   
    if($id != ''){
        $this->db->where("id !=", $id);
    }
    $query1 = $this->db->get();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($query1);
    die();

    return $query1->result();
}
```

And my View Part is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email address</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required email" id="email"  name="email" maxlength="128">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">User Name</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="username"  name="username" maxlength="128">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

my email validation is called perfectly but my username validation is not calling perfectly.
It is showing the error of call_fun.....
this is for check email or username is already exits or not

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin in localhost and mysql

Comment: @ParthKhatri please check my below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162050/when-i-call-function-its-given-me-error-why/57189673#57189673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my below code, You don't need to separate controller function for checking Username or Email already exists or not. You can combine into one controller function.

It also works both times i.e. in Registration and in Editing Profile.

**Controller :-**

```
public function fieldcheck()
{
    if( $this->input->is_ajax_request() && ( $this->input->post('email') || $this->input->post('username') ) )
    {
        if( $this->input->post('id') )
        {
            $id = $this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('id'));
        }
        else
        {
            $id = 0;
        }

        if( $this->input->post('email') )
        {
            $field = 'email';
            $fieldvalue = $this->input->post('email');
        }
        if( $this->input->post('username') )
        {
            $field = 'username';
            $fieldvalue = $this->input->post('username');
        }

        if($field)
        {
            //Loading Model File
            $this->load->model('user_model');

            $result = $this->user_model->checkExists($id,$field,$fieldvalue);
            if ($result == 'new')
            {
                echo json_encode( array('result'=>'new') );
                die();
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode( array('result'=>'old') );
                die();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('user', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

**Model :-**

```
//Querying to Check E-mail or Username is already exists
function checkExists($id,$field,$fieldvalue)
{
    switch($field)
    {
        case 'email'        : $dbfield = 'email';break;
        case 'username'     : $dbfield = 'username';break;
    }
    if($id != 0)
    {
        $option = array( 'id !=' => $id, $dbfield => $fieldvalue );
    }
    else
    {
        $option = array( $dbfield => $fieldvalue );
    }

    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($option);
    //die();

    $query = $this->db->get_where('admins', $option);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return 'old';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'new';
    }
}
```

**View :-**

Here, 1 suggestion. Please use  for Email Address Input field.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Email address</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
   <input type="email" class="form-control required email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="128" onchange="checkusername(this.value);">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">User Name</label><span style="color: red">*</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="username" name="username" maxlength="128" onchange="checkemail(this.value);">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript :-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
function checkemail(email)
{
    var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if( trim(email) != '' && filter.test(trim(email)) )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            url         :   "<?php echo site_url('user/fieldcheck');?>", //Controller Name / Function Name
            data        :   { <?php if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'edit' ) echo "'id' : ".$user[0]['id'].", "; ?> 'email' : email },
            dataType    : "json",
            cache       : false,
            success     :   function(data){
                            if( data.result == 'old')
                            {
                                alert('E-mail already Taken.');
                                return false;
                            }
                }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter valid E-mail Id.');
        return false;
    }
}
function checkusername(username)
{
    if( trim(username) != '' )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            url         :   "<?php echo site_url('user/fieldcheck');?>", //Controller Name / Function Name
            data        :   { <?php if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'edit' ) echo "'id' : ".$user[0]['id'].", "; ?> 'username' : username },
            dataType    : "json",
            cache       : false,
            success     :   function(data){
                            if( data.result == 'old')
                            {
                                alert('Username already Taken.');
                                return false;
                            }
                }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter Username.');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope above codes helps.